# GNOME Remote Desktop RDP credentials present when those were never set up manually

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, credentials

I discovered via the passwords and keys dialog that my installation of Ubuntu 20.04 has a an entry "GNOME Remote Desktop RDP credentials" with a password which I have never manually entered.

Is this expected behaviour (like a default password, it appears to be randomly generated) or should I worry about an intrusion?

Screen sharing appears to be disabled in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the article
[GNOME Remote Desktop - RDP setup guide](https://gitlab.gnome.org/-/snippets/1778)
which might explain this credential.

According to the article, this credential belongs to the *RDP server*
(as distinct from the client).
It perhaps was introduced starting with version 40 of `gnome-remote-desktop`
when it gained support for RDP, because
the RDP server in gnome-remote-desktop currently didn't have the UI to
setup it yet.

The article describes how to write, compile and run a tiny program that
creates this credential. If you have not done so, this credential may
now have been incorporated officially into the `gnome-remote-desktop`
package.